# Meaning of $\sim$?

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

I often read $f(x) \sim g(x)$ and I wonder what the Standard Interpretation of this $\sim$ is. 
It seems to mean something like asymptotically equally distributed, something like
$f(x)=g(x)(1+o(1))$.

But I wonder, if $f(x)= c g(x)$, is it true that then $f(x) \sim g(x)$? Because with the above Definition with $o(1)$ this would not be the case?

I ask because of the following example:
It is written:
$${{k-1} \choose {x-1}} p^{x} (1-p)^{k-x} \sim {{k-1} \choose {x-1}} p^x$$

Now I wonder whether it holds that 
$$ c {{k-1} \choose {x-1}} p^{x} (1-p)^{k-x} \sim {{k-1} \choose {x-1}} p^x$$

Comment: I've known $f\sim g$ to mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) /g(x) =1$.

Comment: what should be the same as $f(x)=g(x)(1+o(1))$, then. 
But then, it obviously does not hold that $c \cdot f(x) \sim f(x)$?
So how does one get to the Statement above, that one can leave out $(1-p)^{k-x}$? One Needs to say that this asymptotics is neither for $k,x,p$ but for $n$ which does not occur in this formula.

Answer (score 3):

Near x=a :  $ f(x) \sim g(x) $ means $ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1 $

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. This means that $c f(x) \sim f(x)$ is wrong, isn't it?
So could you tell me how one derives this first Statement 
$${{k-1} \choose {x-1}} p^{x} (1-p)^{k-x} \sim {{k-1} \choose {x-1}} p^x$$

Comment: Before all, what is the variable used for this assymptotic approximation ?  What is the limit considered ?

Comment: The Limit is $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $n^{-1} \ll p \ll n^{-\frac{1}{x}}$, $x$ and $k$ are constants, Independent from $n$.

Comment: If $p \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ then the statement is obviously true, isn't it?