# What is meant by the notation $\sim$

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964944/asymptotics-of-inverse-of-normal-cdf), I then was unsure what the exact definition of the notation $\sim$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966269/762889)

Comment: It means “is distributed as” or “has the distribution”.

Comment: Depending on the context, $\sim$ could mean many things, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858917/meaning-of-sim?rq=1).

Comment: I read $\sim$ as "approximately". So if we're interested in $x$ near $0$ I might say $\sin(x) \sim x$. The definition provided in the link given by @DietrichBurde makes this notation precise but "approximately" read well when you're parsing symbols.

Comment: @TianVlašić I added the link to the answer I was looking at, which gives the context in which I was unsure with the notation. In the answer I was looking at, I do not think they are using it to denote how something is distributed, but more related to asymptotics.

Comment: @DylanDijk Oh, OK.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) \sim g(x)$ means $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$ and is called asymptotic equivalence.

Edit: by looking at the linked by OP answer, I can conclude the notation there means [Asymptotic series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion).

Comment: More generally, it means $f(x) = g(x) +o(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0$, where $x_0$ is some accumulation point of the common domain of the functions. It can also indicate an asymptotic expansion.